# Ruby on Rails Error. Processing Controller method as png

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have given this in my route.

```
get '/custom_page/:name' => 'custom_page#load_content'
```

And this is my controller method.

```
def load_content
    page_name = (params[:name]).split("_").join(" ")
    p "---------------------"
    p page_name
end
```

Thing is im getting 2 get calls inside my console. and hence an error.
here is what my console looks like..

```
Started GET "/en/custom_page/Nidhin_Test_Page" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-12 11:50:34 +0530
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `schema_migrations`.* FROM `schema_migrations`
Processing by CustomPageController#load_content as HTML
  Parameters: {"locale"=>"en", "name"=>"Nidhin_Test_Page"}
  "---------------------"    
  "Nidhin Test Page"
  Rendered custom_page/load_content.html.erb within layouts/calculator (2.4ms)
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 2 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  Rendered layouts/_calculator_script_top.html.erb (45.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_calculator_header.html.erb (217.5ms)
  MenuItem Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `menu_items`.* FROM `menu_items` ORDER BY `menu_items`.`menu_priority` ASC
  Rendered layouts/_calculator_menu.html.erb (15.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_calculator_script_bottom.html.erb (0.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 325ms (Views: 295.8ms | ActiveRecord: 3.9ms)


Started GET "/en/custom_page/favicon.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-12 11:50:35 +0530
Processing by CustomPageController#load_content as PNG
  Parameters: {"locale"=>"en", "name"=>"favicon"}
"---------------------"
"favicon"
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6ms
  Rendered /home/nithin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/exception_notification-4.0.1/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/_request.text.erb (3.3ms)
  Rendered /home/nithin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/exception_notification-4.0.1/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/_title.text.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered /home/nithin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/exception_notification-4.0.1/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/_session.text.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered /home/nithin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/exception_notification-4.0.1/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/_title.text.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered /home/nithin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/exception_notification-4.0.1/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/_environment.text.erb (3.2ms)
  Rendered /home/nithin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/exception_notification-4.0.1/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/_title.text.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered /home/nithin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/exception_notification-4.0.1/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/_backtrace.text.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered /home/nithin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/exception_notification-4.0.1/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/exception_notification.text.erb (34.7ms)

An ActionView::MissingTemplate occurred in custom_page#load_content:

  Missing template custom_page/load_content with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:png], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee, :arb]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/nithin/mobomo/Projects/sfth/app/views"
  * "/home/nithin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bundler/gems/active_admin-c4a123d48850/app/views"
  * "/home/nithin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/kaminari-0.15.0/app/views"
  * "/home/nithin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/devise-3.2.2/app/views"
```

Why is that favicon coming? How to prevent this from getting called? `Processing by CustomPageController#load_content as PNG`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many browsers look for `favicon.png` files on your server (that is the icon shown near the title of the page). It is a known symptom seeing [404s for `favicon.png`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#Limitations_and_criticism) in server logs.

The easiest way to avoid a browser looking at internal links for a `favicon` is to put a `favicon.ico` at the website root, or to add a [`<link rel`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#How_to_use) to your layout template:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://example.com/myicon.ico" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, why are you outputting directly in your action:

```
def load_content
    page_name = (params[:name]).split("_").join(" ")
    p "---------------------"
    p page_name
end
```

This needs to be as follows:

```
def load_content
    @page_name = (params[:name]).split("_").join(" ") #-> sends @page_name to the view, where you'll be able to render the `-------------`
end
```

Even if you're trying to render a `png` directly, I'd still advise against outputting directly from your `controller`. It's against MVC principles, and will make debugging & upgrading your app extremely difficult in future

---

**Favicon**

The `favicon` issue comes in here:

```
Started GET "/en/custom_page/favicon.png"
```

Your route consists of the following:

```
get '/custom_page/:name'
```

This means whenever you send a request to `custom_page/_______.png`, your controller will pick up the `:name` param & use that

As to *why* you're getting the `favicon.png` loaded, I can only guess as we've not got much to work from. You're getting your expected result, so the problem is likely in *how* this is being called / rendered

The two issues I could see would be:

> - Turbolinks
> - Layout

The first (turbolinks), would be a javascript issue. I don't know why it would render `favicon.png`, so I would recommend you test removing `require turbolinks` from your `application.js` file

The second (layout), is what my hunch tells me is the problem. If you're rendering a layout with this action, it would try and call the likes of `favicon.png`. To fix that, I would try using `layout false` in the controller to see if it fixes the issue

Hope this helps!

Comment: render layout: false did help me.. but actualy i want the load_content.html.erb to be rendered too.. so how to?

Comment: `load_content.html.erb` is a view? This will be rendered each time you call the view. The layout is different than the view - if you let me know what code you're using for `load_content.html.erb`, it will be much better

Comment: yea its a view.. I have that it my file structure. I want to write somethign in it.. Actualy the output looks fine.. Whatever inside the html page is geting displayed. But its in console that im geting this error. I want to stop the controler geting rendered as png. But i want to render the html page

Comment: @RichPeck +1 for figuring out the issue, Nidhin where are you loading favicon.png in your `load_content` view?

Comment: As i said..load_content view is blank. nothing is inside that page..
any way i solved the issue by change :name to someother variable in routes

Comment: Thanks RSB - I figured this was about how to structure the app more than a specific syntax issue

Comment: @RichPeck that issue is still exist when i updated to the server..
all changes i made in local was changing :name to :page_name to remove the error from local..
now if change that to :name in my local that error is still not there. Why is this. And also if i do the same in my server will this issue go?

Comment: try removing the favicon tag in your application layout

Answer (score 3):

Somehow the router is not realizing that that is an asset request.

Do you really need to define the route like that?
if so, you could define the route like

```
get '/custom_page/:name' => 'custom_page#load_content', format: :html
```

So the request asking for a `png` format will not be routed to your controller.

Anyway I would try to use the `resources` method in the `routes.rb`:

```
resources :custom_page, only: :show
```

Note that this will use the standard rails naming, so you have to adjust a little your code:

First, rename the `custom_page_controller.rb` to `custom_pages_controller.rb` (controller names are, by convention, plural names) and second, you will be receiving the page name under the `id` param, instead of `name`.

So your method should look like this:

```
def load_content
  page_name = (params[:id]).split("_").join(" ")
  p "---------------------"
  p page_name
end
```

Regarding why you are receiving this request: The browser always tries to load the site's favicon (that is the tab's icon you see in almost all pages). I think if you don't provide the `meta-tag` for it, the browser tries to guess the url.

To have the `meta-tag`, you can use the `favicon_link_tag` helper in your layout's `head` and then have the image, usually called `favicon.png`, in your `app/assets/images/` or in your `public` folder.