# Error favicon.ico same as query in show page rails 4.2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

- I had a problem about favicon.ico in show page.
- And i tried to search and apply these solutions but it still failure. Here are some result which i found but i didn't successfully.

  - [Ruby on Rails Error. Processing Controller method as png](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23602376/ruby-on-rails-error-processing-contoller-method-as-png)
- This is problem show in production.log

This is my log:

```
Started GET "/videos/favicon.ico" for 42.112.87.124 at 2015-07-12 19:26:54 +0700
Processing by VideosController#show as 
Parameters: {"id"=>"favicon"}
Video Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `videos`.* FROM `videos` WHERE `videos`.`id` = 0 LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms
```

And this is code in my `application.html.erb`

```
<%= favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico' %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag  'application', media: 'all'%>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

And this is my `routes.rb`:

```
resources :videos, only: [:index, :show]
```

- But everytime i called to action show, it always returned a `params[:id]="favicon"`. And i didn't understand why it happened ?.
- Hope everybody can explain for me. Thank you very much.

Comment: Where is the `favicon.ico` file placed?

Comment: @Deep I put it inside `app/assets/images` directory.

Comment: Do you have `require turbolinks` in `application.js`, if yes then try removing that.

Comment: @Deep I've just shown my `application.html.erb` in my question and I didn't put `turbolinks` in `application.js`.

Comment: try remove 'favicon.ico'  from the favicon_link_tag, use `<%= favicon_link_tag %>`, and let us know what this produces as html

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<%= favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico' %>
```

to

```
<%= favicon_link_tag '/favicon.ico' %>
```

to load the favicon from the server's root instead of the folder relative to the document.